# React Native - Is there any best way to give the style `borderRadius` each button?

Tags: react-native, styles, mapping, border-radius

I have created three buttons using `map`, and the 1st and the 3rd buttons have `borderRadius` on the side.

This is what it looks like :

[image: As you can see, button one and two should have borderRadius]

Even though I anyways displayed the buttons as expected, but I feel like this code should be better than I did. Plus, I am not so sure if it is okay to map the buttons in this way..

My code below :

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    marginRight: 15,
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  btnWrap: {
    width: 50,
    height: 24,
    backgroundColor: colors.white_two,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: colors.very_light_pink_five,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    color: colors.very_light_pink_five,
  },
  btnLeft: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 6,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 6,
  },
  btnRight: {
    borderTopRightRadius: 6,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 6,
  },
  btnMiddle: {
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderRightWidth: 0,
  },
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: colors.black,
  },
  selectedText: {
    color: colors.white_two,
  },
});


const pointType = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const MypagePoint = ({ totalPoint }) => {
  const [btnClicked, setBtnClicked] = useState(null);

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container]}>
      
      <View style={[styles.row, { marginBottom: 15 }]}>
        {pointType.map((type, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[
              styles.btnWrap,
              btnClicked === index && styles.selected,

              // This is the part I doubt
              index === 0 && styles.btnLeft,
              index === 1 && styles.btnMiddle,
              index === 2 && styles.btnRight,
            ]}
            onPress={() => setBtnClicked(index)}
          >
            <Text
              style={[
                styles.textStyle,
                btnClicked === index && styles.selectedText,
              ]}
            >
              {type}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Would you let me know the best way to code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Old Solution**: Use ternary operator instead.

**Updated**: Create a helper function and use the rounded corner styling only for the first and last buttons.

Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/bold-strawberries)

[image]

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    marginRight: 15,
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  btnWrap: {
    width: 50,
    height: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'pink',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: -2,
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    color: 'pink',
  },
  btnLeft: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 6,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 6,
  },
  btnRight: {
    borderTopRightRadius: 6,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 6,
  },
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  selectedText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});

const pointType = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];

export default MypagePoint = ({ totalPoint }) => {
  const [btnClicked, setBtnClicked] = useState(null);

  const buttonStyle = (index) => {
    if (index === 0) return styles.btnLeft;
    else if (index === pointType.length - 1) return styles.btnRight;
  };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container]}>
      <View style={[styles.row, { marginBottom: 15 }]}>
        {pointType.map((type, index) => (
          <Button
            index={index}
            btnClicked={btnClicked}
            buttonStyle={buttonStyle}
            setBtnClicked={setBtnClicked}
            type={type}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const Button = ({ index, btnClicked, buttonStyle, setBtnClicked, type }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[
        styles.btnWrap,
        btnClicked === index && styles.selected,
        buttonStyle(index),
      ]}
      onPress={() => setBtnClicked(index)}>
      <Text
        style={[styles.textStyle, btnClicked === index && styles.selectedText]}>
        {type}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: Right.. I can use ternary operator to look tidy. Can I ask if it is okay to use `map` for the buttons..?

Comment: map looks neat to me. but as there are only three buttons, you might as well made a new component and rendered it without using map.

Comment: That is what I did at first, but the problem i faced was I couldn't change the style of the button which is selected as there is no `index` if I don't use map..

Comment: Thank you, but have one more question. So anyways, I need to use map even after making the button component in order to change the color of selected button? What if there are only two buttons, but still need to map them..?

Comment: We can use conditional rendering where we will compare first and last button. Wait will show you an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229346/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-uheny).